# When are Wasserstein spaces $CAT(\kappa)$?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-probability, optimal-transportation

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete and separable metric space and, for $1\leq p<\infty$, let $(\mathcal{P}_p(X,d),W_p)$ be the $p$-Wasserstein space on $(X,d)$.  For which $p$ and $(X,d)$ is $(\mathcal{P}_p(X,d),W_p)$ a $CAT(\kappa)$ space?

---

I know that for $p=2$ and $(X,d)$ a Banach space, $(\mathcal{P}_2(X,d),W_2)$ is a Hadamard ($CAT(0)$) space; but there must be other cases...

Comment: Your statement "I know that..." might hold ONLY for Hilbert spaces!

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Is it even true for Hilbert spaces?  I can't actually see why (or find a reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost never...

Note that there is an isometric embedding $X\to W_p(X)$, so $X$ has to be CAT(κ). Second the space $W_p(X)$ contains symmetric $p$-product $S^n(X)=X^{\times n}/S_n$ so $p=2$, or $X$ is one a point-space.
Now if $\dim X>1$, then you get into trouble with extending geodesic thru a $\delta$-measure in $S^2(X)$, so you get $\dim X\le1$.

Comment: I was thinking, is $\mathcal{W}_p(X)$ ever locally $CAT(\kappa)$?  Or does something rule that out also?

Comment: $X$ could be one-point space, or $\mathbb{R}$, maybe a tree.